# How to restrict the access of non published post URL for logged-in users?

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

I am trying to restrict the logged-in users to access their drafted post preview URL.

For example, If a user is having a post named "my-post" with post_status and post_id are draft and 10, then URL structure looks like https://example.com/?post_type=post-type-name&p=10

Is there any hook/filter that will restrict the access to post preview?

Thanks!